# Django - Global variable, Should I use Template context processor?

Tags: django, django-templates, global-variables

my question is: 
Should I use Template context processor for global variable like category list ?

I have globs.py

```
from news.models import Category

def globs(request):
    cats = Category.objects.all()
    return {'cats': cats}
```

and in settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.core.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"globs.globs",)
```

And when I use in template 'cats' it works fine on developer server.

On my hosting I have a problem:
Error importing request processor module globs: "No module named globs"

Can I use something else for global variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

globs.py needs to be in your importable path on your hosting server.  You could move it to your news directory and use "news.globs.globs" in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.